# System.AggregateException on GetStringAsync in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to call an API like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiKey", Token);
**var result = await client.GetStringAsync(GetUrl($"accounts/{accountID}/menu?skip=0&limit=1"));**
var menuList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Menu>>(result);
```

but getting  System.AggregateException on GetStringAsync, error CS0103: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context

and Exception Message

One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)

I see that this is returned in result
 Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}

I tried to make call using postman with same url and apikey in header and I see the results.

Can you please suggest what is wrong with above code. Api key expects only an apiKey in header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime that an async call fails you'll get an `AggregateException`, what's important is the inner exception within that.

It looks like your inner exception is 404 Not Found, which means that you're not calling the correct URL.

You said it's working in postman, that's great.  To find the root cause I suggest the following:

1. Start Fiddler
2. Make the call through postman, view the request in Fiddler
3. Make the call through your C# code, view the request in Fiddler

Comparing the Postman request against the C# request should tell you where the error is.